# Rename [bacon] tag to [kevin-bacon] and add [bacon] as a synonym for [bacon.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I just fixed 3 different questions tagged with [bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bacon) where the intention was to use [bacon.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bacon.js).

As of now, [bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bacon) refers to "Related to Kevin Bacon and/or shortest path problems." [bacon.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bacon.js) refers to the "functional reactive programming library for Javascript".

I think the best fix would be to rename [bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bacon) to [kevin-bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kevin-bacon) and add [bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bacon) as a synonym for [bacon.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bacon.js).

Comment: Kevin Bacon and/or shortest path problems? Either an actor or some random problem? Weirdest most useless tag I've seen yet.

Comment: @Gimby, that's [a meme of some kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon). Apparently people like to compute the shortest paths from any actor to Kevin Bacon. Obviously they should do that with Robert Downey, Jr. instead.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Okay less weird tag description, still weird that it exists AS a tag :)

Comment: I'm against having a tag for the Bacon number at all. There is a [shortest path tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path) which should be used instead. And even if it were to be decided that the concept deserves its own tag, it should be namend [bacon-number] as that's the official term, derived from the [Erdős number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_number#Variations).

Comment: l4mpi I'm fine with removing the tag, but don't have a strong opinion about it. My problem is that questions I'm interested in are mis-tagged.

Comment: Note that `kevin-bacon` is used denote node connectivity as opposed to shortest path specifically (though relatedly), for which `bacon-number` is correct

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: [six-degrees-of-separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) seems like a much better tag name

Comment: Google has a built in bacon number calculator: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS527US594&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bacon%20number%20bruce%20willis

Comment: @Erdősnumber `I'm against having a tag for the Bacon number at all` _says the competing [shortest distance number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Bacon_number)..._ :)

Comment: @DavidGrinberg That's not that user's name.

Comment: @Tom I Failed... totally misread that. I was wondering why I was having trouble @ mentioning it...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but [Oracle of Bacon](http://oracleofbacon.org/) sounds much better than Oracle of Downey Jr.

Comment: @topher, although that's subjective, I have to admit you're right :)